# is there any way to convert my mysql query into power bi dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Select col1,'EOI' as col4,col2  from (
Select 'EOI' as col1,count(drmca_epcsubcontdtls_fk) as col2 from drmaincontanalytics_tbl where drmca_l1evnttype=1
union 
select 'EOI' as col1,count( drsubcontanalytics_pk) as col2 from drsubcontanalytics_tbl where drsca_l2evnttyp=1
)
```

I need to implement this query in dax

I tried this measure but i cannot figure out how to take union in x1 and x2

```
MEOI_TENDSTATUS =
VAR X1 =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( drmaincontanalytics_tbl[drmca_epcsubcontdtls_fk] ),
    drmaincontanalytics_tbl[drmca_l1evnttype] = 1,
    drmaincontanalytics_tbl[drmca_tendstatus] = 5
)
VAR X2 =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( drsubcontanalytics_tbl[drsca_epcsubcontdtls_fk] ),
    drsubcontanalytics_tbl[drsca_l2evnttyp] = 1,
    drsubcontanalytics_tbl[drsca_tendstatus] = 5
)
RETURN
X1 + X2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating your table variables, X1 and X2**

`DISTINCTCOUNT()` returns a number, so your `X1` and `X2` variables are numbers, hence your `X1 + X2` calculation is just going to give you the sum.

You can use `FILTER()` to return a table, for example:

```
VAR X1 = FILTER(drmaincontanalytics_tbl, drmaincontanalytics_tbl[drmca_l1evnttype] = 1)
```

This will return the entire table with the applied filters. If you want to return a one column table, you can wrap this in a [SELECTCOLUMNS()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) function.

**Appending the table variables with UNION()**

There's a `UNION()` function in DAX which you can use to replicate the SQL equivalent. It takes table functions as arguments. Once you've defined your table variables properly, you'll be able to append them like this:

```
VAR X1 = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER())
VAR X2 = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER())
RETURN

UNION(X1, X2)
```

Finally, if you're trying to return a table which you can use in your data model, make sure you're creating this via the "New Table" option, not "New Column" or "New Measure".

Alternatively, you can write SQL directly in your source in query view if you navigate to 'Advanced Options' for the 'Source' step.

Comment: It's working right . but im facing a problem when i create a new table i cannot use filters for that table.This new table becomes solo entity

Comment: If you are trying to use filters from other tables, you'll need to make sure they're related in your data model (see relationship tab in report view).

Comment: If this works can you close it off? If you have a separate query about table relationships I'd suggest posting as a new question.